# Can you use "$=$" instead of "$\Leftrightarrow$"

Tags: logic, convention

In my homework problem I shall proof the distributive law for logical statements. However instead of the equivalence arrow "$\Leftrightarrow$" the equal sign was used to state the problem. But I thought it's wrong to use "$=$" in a logical statement.

The following was stated:

Proof the following distributive law for statments A,B,C:

$A\wedge(B\vee C)=A\wedge B\vee A\wedge C$

Comment: There is a delicate issue here on what exactly do you mean when you write a proposition, and you are technically correct that equality is not the usual way to write this (perhaps $\equiv$ which is not $=$ was used, or by mistake $=$). But there are ways to think about this where using $=$ does make sense. However, I'd generally attribute this to an abuse of notation (which is still something I wouldn't do in an intro course).

Comment: No, the use of the equal sign in in such a case appeared mutliple times troughout the cours so far.

Comment: In wich cases would it make sense if I might ask

Comment: The right thing to do about this is to contact your professor or teaching assistant and request clarifications.

Comment: If you treat proposition as subsets of some universal sets (in which case the proposition $A$ is the same as $x\in A$, and $\land$ becomes $\cap$, etc), then equivalence means that the two statements define the same set, and since it's the same set, the equality sign is justified. Similarly if you declare in advance that you consider two propositions to be equal if they have the same truth value under any assignment (which is what you'd usually define as "logically equivalent" and denote with $\iff$). This is an uncommon approach, but it is valid. (I wouldn't use it, though.)

Comment: And it becomes a downright terrible approach when discussing first-order logic, where "$=$" is a symbol of the language. E.g. the expression "$\forall x\exists y(x=y)=\exists x(x=x)$" is pretty awful.

Comment: Personally, I insist on using $\Leftrightarrow$ (for reasons such as Noah's), but there are plenty of books that use the $=$ here as well.  As Asaf says, best thing to do is just ask your professor.

Comment: @Noah: I absolutely agree with you. But do note that a lot of times these sort of questions, like the distributive laws come well before first-order logic. And sometimes there is little to no extension of the curriculum into FOL (or even predicate calculus), so I can imagine teachers in that situation more freely using $=$ like that.